# Create new Python dictionary from specific values from another dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I have a dictionary with multiple entries

```
res = {'status': 'done', 'nextLogId': 'AQAAAXb', 'logs': [{'content': {'service': 't2pipeline', 'tags': ['tag1:value1', 'tag2:value2', 'tag3:value3'], 'timestamp': '2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z', 'host': 'i-00e17b8e872ec7d05', 'attributes': {'caller': 'psignal/state_machine.go:451', 'ts': 1609824303.416246, 'level': 'warn'}, 'message': 'psignal: Ignoring scte35 segmentation_descriptor (type:Program Start eventID:0 refUTC:Jan  5 05:25:02.387626333): there is an active segment with the same event_id'}, 'id': 'AQAAAXb'}, {'content': {'service': 't2pipeline', 'tags': ['tag1:value1', 'tag2:value2', 'tag3:value3'], 'timestamp': '2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z', 'host': 'i-00e17b8e872ec7d05', 'attributes': {'caller': 'psignal/state_machine.go:713', 't2': {'scte35': {'event_id': 0, 'event_ptr': '0xc009f32b40', 'seg_type_id': 16}}, 'ts': 1609824303.4161847, 'level': 'info'}, 'message': 'psignal: scte35 segdesc eventID:0 type:Program Start'}, 'id': 'AQAAAXb'}], 'requestId': 'OVZRd3hv'}
```

I am trying to create a new dictionary with certain key values including timestamp and message only. I do this in a loop but only the last iteration is present in the dictionary.

```
new_dict = {}
for i in range(len(res['logs'])):
    new_dict['timestamp'] = res['logs'][i]['content']['timestamp']
    new_dict['message'] = res['logs'][i]['content']['message']
```

When I print outside the loop I see only the last entry

```
print(new_dict)
```

This is the result
`{'timestamp': '2021-01-05T05:25:03.416Z', 'message': 'psignal: scte35 segdesc eventID:0 type:Program Start'}`

How do I make it so the new dictionary is updated with both entries. I tried `dict.update()` but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a list:

```
list_of_dict = []
for i in range(len(res['logs'])):
    new_dict = {}
    new_dict['timestamp'] = res['logs'][i]['content']['timestamp']
    new_dict['message'] = res['logs'][i]['content']['message']
    list_of_dict.append(new_dict)
```